# How to configure JIRA_HOME?

Tags: jira

How to configure JIRA_HOME? I'm getting an error:

> Configured jira.home '/Users/codedroid/Downloads/atlassian-jira-5.1-standalone' must not be a parent directory of the webapp servlet path '/Users/codedroid/Downloads/atlassian-jira-5.1-standalone/atlassian-jira'

Changed it and now I get this:

> Configured jira.home '/Users/codedroid/Downloads/atlassian-jira-5.1-standalone/atlassian-jira' must not be the same as the webapp servlet path '/Users/codedroid/Downloads/atlassian-jira-5.1-standalone/atlassian-jira'

Comment: Problem was the JIRA documentation.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Have a look in here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Setting+your+JIRA+Home+Directory), if you're still having troubles please write what did you set JIRA_HOME to be and where did you defined it, thanks.

**EDIT**

Yea, that documentation is more of 'how to' instead of 'what'. A better explanation of what the JIRA_HOME should be is writen in more details [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+Home+Directory).

Anyway, if you feel that the documentation are confusing or just bad, you could do everyone a favour and write it at the bottom of the page, under comments, so other could see it easily.

Comment: I ran the console application. console.sh  and just selected the directory.  If I put anything above atlassian-jira it gives the parent error.  If I put it at atlassian-jira it gives me the must not be same as the webapp servlet path error?

Comment: (warning) However, avoid locating the JIRA Home Directory inside the JIRA Installation Directory.

Answer (score 2):

The JIRA documentation does NOT! make it clear even to a seasoned programmer that this JIRA_HOME directory is referring to a data directory and not the installation directory.  If there are any JIRA folks out there please fix this outragious misunderstanding in your documentation. JAVA_HOME refers to you guessed it the installation location of java.  Its called a 'convention' if you want to invent some other meaning please say so it your documentation and don't wast valuable developer time on installing your productivity tool. Think its not a problem?  Google 'must not be the same as the webapp servlet path' and see what you get back.  Thanks for wasting my afternoon, and no doubt the time of many others.

```
  (warning) However, avoid locating the JIRA Home Directory inside the JIRA Installation Directory.
```

This appears in only documentation point and is not the first place people look as noted above

Answer (score 1):

Just create a folder named JIRA, then set the environment variable `JIRA_HOME` as `D:\JIRA`, as well as the application properties file.

```
# jira-application.properties
jira.home = D:\\JIRA
```

Don't be confused with the `JAVA_HOME`, `JIRA_HOME` has absolutely nothing to do with the folder of your zip ball downloaded from official website.

Comment: Why do you assume D:?  Or is that just an example?

Answer (score 0):

JIRA_HOME is an empty folder where JIRA will create everything it needs in a RUNTIME.
It is NOT a folder where your unpacked JIRA distribution resides.

P.S. yes it is confusing still in 2021

Answer (score 0):

If you install jira software .tar.gz file, extract it either using 7zip or using cmd with command

```
tar -xzvf filename.tar.gz
```

Then use appropriate Java version. (I am using jre1.8 with JRE_HOME environment variable. I also have jdk18 set up with JAVA_HOME which didn't work, so i am using JRE) I have downloaded Jira version 9.12.3

Then create a new folder outside the jira installation folder. (I extracted jira at 'D:/Softwares/atlassian-jira/' and I am creating the new folder 'D:/JIRA'.)

Set this path as JIRA_HOME in the system environment variables.

Then go to jira installation directory, in the folder: "\atlassian-jira\WEB-INF\classes".

Find 'jira-application.properties' file and edit it using text/code editor/notepad. Add the jira home path to it (D:/JIRA in my case)

Then go back to installation folder and go to bin folder.

Run strt-jira.bat file. (If you run it in cmd, you can see the output if any error occurs or else the file closes by itself).

If no error, open browser and go to 'localhost:8080' for further setup.